# Post processing after Spring cloud stream Function

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace

Simple function like below can be consume and produce message.

```
@Bean
public Function<String, String> toUpperCase() {
    return s -> s.toUpperCase();
}
```

Is there any option in spring cloud stream to return control to the application after publishing/supplying a message?

I have an use case to update state in database after publishing the message.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Consumer` instead of a `Function` and send the result using the `StreamBridge` instead.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources

Comment: Thanks Gary! Tilak, here is an example using Solace & SCSt since you tagged both: https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-spring/blob/master/cloud-stream-dynamic-destination-processor/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/spring/scs/DynamicDestinationProcessor.java#L65:L81

Comment: Thanks Gary and Mrc0113

Comment: So there is nothing similar to error handler which gets invoked for publish errors. I was expecting there will be a success handler which gets invoked after successful publish.

Comment: I am not familiar with any mechanisms the Solace binder might provide but, for example, the Kafka MessageChannel binder has a couple of mechanisms: 1) Make the binding synchronous and the send will block until it is successful (or fails). 2) Configure a message channel to receive async send results.

Comment: @Mrc0113, Spring cloud stream had added support for post processing https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_post_processing_after_sending_message.  With "spring-cloud.version" 2022.0.4, "solace-spring-cloud-bom.version" 3.0.0 and "spring-boot-starter-parent" 3.1.0, got it working for producing and consuming single message. For batch processor, it shows ClassCastException at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:738).

Comment: @Mrc0113 are there any samples for batch publish with post processing? Thanks

Comment: @GaryRussell Post processing method https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_post_processing_after_sending_message is invoked on publish success or failure. Is there an option to find out whether publish was successful or not?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. I am not familiar with that mechanism. Ask a new question.